# Callback when App is killed - React Native

Tags: ios, react-native

Is there a way to execute an action when a React Native app terminates? I know about app states, but I'm looking for a way to call an action when the user swipes to kill the app, not when it's just in the background.

From my understanding, there is no way in doing this within React Native. Is there a way I could do it natively? I only need this functionality for iOS. Thanks a lot!

Comment: For me, my solution in 2024 is to have foreground service (check out notifee), and if it doesn't work, use push notification so users can click on it to launch.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you've got to go native code. In the AppDelegate you need to implement the method

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application;
```

[more info about applicationWillTerminate](http://-%20(void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication%20*)application;)

inside of it you can resolve a Promise that you defined in our [module](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-ios)